# React Hook Form: useForm not returning any errors in formState

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod, t3-app

I am creating a app using T3 stack + react-hook-form + zodResolver:@hookform/resolvers/zod

I have a zod schema defined as below

```
export const AccountSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string().uuid().optional(),
  title: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Title is required' }),
  description: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Description is required' }),
});

export type Account = z.infer<typeof AccountSchema>;
```

And in a component I am making use of useForm Hook as below

```
const editForm = useForm<Account>({ resolver: async (val, ctx, opt) => {
    const res = await zodResolver(AccountSchema)(val, ctx, opt);
    console.log('Validation Result: ', res, val);
    return zodResolver(AccountSchema)(val, ctx, opt);
  }});
```

form Submit Handler:

```
onSubmit={void editForm.handleSubmit(() => console.log('success'), (val) => console.log('Errors: ', val))}
```

Packages used:

```
"zod" -> "3.20.7"
"@hookform/resolvers" -> "2.9.11"
"react-hook-form" -> "7.43.5"
```

**Issue:**
Looking at the console log, I can see zodResolver is passing correct errors to useForm resolver but in the formState object errors is always undefined
ie: editForm.formState.errors.title is always returning as undefined.
Also on submit always reloads the page irrespective of the form being valid or invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.
The "void" before handleSubmit was causing the issue.
Had added void due to eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises rule.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it just happened to me and turned out that I'm calling the wrong onSubmit action in the form field:

```
const schema = z.object({
  description: z.string().min(3).max(50).nonempty(),
  amount: z.number().min(0).nonnegative(),
  category: z.enum(categories),
});    

type FormData = z.infer<typeof schema>;
    
    const DataForm = () => {
      const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
      } = useForm<FormData>({ resolver: zodResolver(schema) });
```

Then, changing the form onSubmit solved the issue:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>
```

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Sadly for me the page reloads on submit irrespective of the form is valid or not.
Have added the onSubmit handler snippet in the question.